# Visual bug when moving a MovieClip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

In my attempt to create a simple Pong-like game, I've encountered a very strange and at times severe visual bug.
When I set the ball (A Flash CS 5.5 library MovieClip) in motion moving around the screen at a rather fast speed, I've noticed that **sometimes** the edges of the ball would be cut-off for a short moment in the direction it is moving.

When it happens, it almost seems like the position of the `ball` MovieClip is slightly ahead of its own border and thus the part that is outside the border fails to get drawn.

Here's a picture that illustrates how this looks - at least for me:
[image]

You can also view the .swf file online here:
http://megaswf.com/serve/2099366

Some technical data:

1. I've been unsuccessful in capturing the with a screenshot no matter how much I tried.
2. Sometimes I would open the .swf and the bug would be almost non-existent while at other times it was very blatant.
3. I'm using an `EnterFrame` event function to increment / decrement the `x` and `y` position of the MovieClip.
4. I have never encountered any such problem in any Flash app, in this machine or others.
5. Truncating / rounding the `x` and `y` values of the `MovieClip` didn't help. Neither did setting `cacheAsBitmap` to true.

**What in the world could be causing this problem?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I couldn't replicate your issue - maybe you have a glitchy version of Flash Player installed? I'm using 11.1.

Comment: Actually I am getting this problem from time to time. It happens when big contrast areas move quickly. Less visible with higher FPS.

It might be system wide. Try to move a window slowly left-right-left-right...

Speaking of which, is it on windows?

Comment: On my mac movement is a bit jerky but not as you described (and I actually know what you mean). And yes, it's not possible to catch it with printscreen.
If you used Timer I'd suspect uneven framerate. Have you read [this](http://www.craftymind.com/2008/04/18/updated-elastic-racetrack-for-flash-9-and-avm2/)? Might be the case. What FPS are you using?

Comment: @valyard on a rather low FPS - say 30 or less, it's *almost* non-existent while on an FPS of 40 and higher it's clearly visible. The .swf I've uploaded uses 60 FPS.

Comment: Are you getting same result in Standalone player and in different browsers?

Comment: @valyard FF, IE, Stand Alone player - all the same. I've played and continue to play many flash games and I've NEVER seen anything like this. Also, the size of the part that is cut-off is directly proportional to the change in position.

Comment: Seeing the problem, FP 11.1, Chrome 16. Taking a look into it.

Comment: ... although I don't notice any problems in the ActionScript. Considering 60 fps, it may simply be one of the more blatant cases of a tearing issue. Try and publish it with hardware acceleration (i.e. wmode direct or GPU) and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: I'm not seeing the rendering problem, but I do see the jerky movement. Try moving a Number variable (e.g. Point) instead of the x/y position of the sprite, and each frame assign its values to the sprite... afaik DisplayObject's x/y values do some rounding (If I remember correctly it was about 1/4 pixel) or at least they used to a few versions back.

Comment: There's rounding to 1/20 — at least in IDE you can increment position only by .05. Have to experiemnt with this a bit.

Comment: A friend of mine took a [photo of this effect](http://i53.tinypic.com/21mt894.jpg) on his machine. This is definitely happening.

Comment: Can you share the code? Or upload FLA somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem, under the same constraints.  As I've added content to my game, this has become more of a problem.  **These options greatly reduce the artifact**:

- Enable JPEG deblocking and increase JPEG Quality (publish settings)
- Decrease framerate
- Enable Hardware acceleration (publish settings)
- Upgrade your Flash Debug Player for Flash Professional
- [Use the non-integrated flash version in Google Chrome](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-google-chrome.html#How_can_I_run_debugger_or_alternate_versions_of_Flash_Player_in_Google_Chrome) (This solved random crashes and fullscreen stutter for me)

Comment: Sorry for all the edits, doing a lot of testing/debugging once I learned deblocking mostly fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact technical reason for this (I'm guessing it has to do with the screen refresh rate vs FPS) but I'm pretty sure its a screen artifact and not a real rendering bug (which is why you won't be able to get it on a screenshot). You can try several things to decrease the effect, like some kind of motion blur:

```
//on your game loop
mc.filters = [new BlurFilter(Math.abs(speed.x), Math.abs(speed.y),3)];
```

Or other visual tweaks... but bare in mind this thing is very noticeable on a black-circle/white-background situation, however on more complex scenarios the eye is much more forgiving.

I'm not sure there is a technical solution (reliable across machines/OSs/browsers), but you can also try with stuff like [optimizing your game loop](http://www.8bitrocket.com/2008/04/08/tutorial-creating-an-optimized-as3-game-timer-loop/) (blitting + steady framerate + [updateAfterEvent()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TimerEvent.html#updateAfterEvent%28%29))... though I'm not sure the result would be as one would like to think (I'm guessing it could help a little).