# How do I animate a ball bouncing on the z axis with Actionscript 3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, animation, actionscript, flash-cs4

I'm having some screen tearing when my ball is animated but not sure if anybody can do anything about that. But my main problem is trying to animate the ball in 3d space. Is there a formula for this?

```
var xPos:Number = tennis_ball.x;
var yPos:Number = tennis_ball.y;
var xVel:Number = (Math.random() * 10) - 5;
var yVel:Number = (Math.random() * -10) - 10;
var gravity:Number = 1;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onLoop, false,0,true);
function onLoop(evt:Event):void {
    yVel += gravity;
    xPos += xVel;
    yPos += yVel;
    if(yPos > 400 - tennis_ball.height){
        yPos = 400 - tennis_ball.height;
        yVel *= -.75;
    }
    tennis_ball.x = xPos;
    tennis_ball.y = yPos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a [common problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058019/visual-bug-when-moving-a-movieclip) usually appearing on Windows. Haven't seen an answer so far.

Comment: Thanks I changed my question to something that someone could probably help me with.